# Algorithm to change an already sampled guitarstring to sound like it was a bit damped by the hand

Tags: c++, algorithm, audio, simulate

I'm trying to simulate the damping of the hand on a guitarstring on an already recorded/sampled open guitarstring sound. I've been trying to use low pass filter and had a moving frequency range but that didn't make it sound like a damped string, just the loss of higher frequencies.

Could someone help me find good material on this, that a human could atleast grasp a bit?
It's going to be implemented in C++ and I have been searching and found almoust everything about the karplus-strong string algorithm, but that's not what I want.. I do want the damping part implemented on a sample of an already recorded real played string.

Comment: maybe you will find more help there http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A low pass sounds like the right idea, honestly. Start with a high cutoff and lower it at a pretty good rate. You might want to try to "fuzz" the cutoff, though. Maybe instead of using a sharp cutoff(all freq>x get cut), just put a negative gain on it based on how far from the cutoff it is?

Comment: The vibration duration of the string should be shorten also. For each note/chord.

Comment: @OP When you say "damping of the hand," are you referring to the practice of the "palm mute" when playing guitar?

Comment: I will step over to the dsp.stackexchange.com for sure, and Geobit that would be worth giving a try. Stephane yes that must be a part of it. Soylent, yes I was/am referring to palm mute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably not as simple as you think. It is not just the right filter, but also the sound will decay faster. This is likely differrent for different frequencies.

If you have guitar at your disposal, you could measure the sound spectum over time when you strike it normally, and once while you dampen it. You can measure the difference in the initial spectrum as well as the difference in decay rate.

You can apply this information to the sound you want to alter, but you'd need to convert the signal to frequency-vs-time first.

But this may be far too complicated for what you had in mind. A simpler approach could be to first increase the decay, by multiplying the signal by e^(w*t), with w as the decay rate. You could split the signal in low and high pass signals and apply different decay rates, with the high freq component getting a faster decay.

Comment: "Split the signal in low and high pass with different decay rates" sounds like an interesting approach, I will try that. But isn't it a change in the resonance when palm muting a string too?

Comment: And I think there are lower frequencies created when hand palm muting that nessesary don't have to exist in the sound from the beginning. Musn't I add something here too?

Comment: @Morgan: That is a possibility. One thing I thought of (but didn't write down) is that one resonation mode (say the 3rd harmonic) will excite other uneven harmonics, causing them to be present in the signal even though they have a very high decay. But if you want to simulate effects like this correctly you maybe need a physical simulation of the string, taking into account non-linearities, perhaps even taking the interaction with the instrument into account. That will be quite an investment. The idea of increasing the decay rate on different bandpass filtered versions will be easier to check.

Comment: Well, I made a low pass filter with a cut-off frequency that is moving from top frequency and down, but it's not falling linear in time it is more like a S in the decay. This is working good enough for me! It sounds like palm mute to me, thanks for helping me.